# How to implement permission in JWT

Tags: node.js, jwt, passport.js, acl, express-jwt

I saw so many posts regarding this subject, but my question is different. !

My app have **session** and **Jwt**,

- **Session**  -  Used for Node ACL  (Using Redis)
- **JWT**      -  For authentication

Now iam trying to remove the node acl and implement permission using JWT

i added all the accessible url to my token **jwt_payload**

```
{
  "id": "5ddb7cb9c525b923505138df",
  "email": "mail@mail.com",
  "permissions": [
    "/admin",
    "/users",
    "/staff",
  ],
  "iat": 1574667849,
  "exp": 1574754249,
  "aud": "admin",
  "iss": "stackoverflow.com",
  "sub": "loginToken"
}
```

*user can access to  /admin, /user ,/staff URL's,*

My question is how to check permission and give allow or error ?

```
var opts = {}
opts.jwtFromRequest = ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken();
opts.secretOrKey = 'your_jwt_secret';

passport.use(new JwtStrategy(opts, function(jwt_payload, done) {
    Admin.findById(jwt_payload.id, function(err, admin) {
        if (err) {
            return done(err, false);
        }
        if (admin) {

            return done(null, admin);
        } else {
            return done(null, false);
        }
    });
}));
```

Comment: You can set the permission in the payload. When You get the token in the request. You can decode it. And check it for the same field(permission) in decoded data.

Comment: how to do that ?

Comment: You have already passed permissions filed to jwt payload. You can user jwt.decode function. This will give you the payload you provided.  refer this doc - https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonwebtoken and search for jwt.decode

Comment: Token valid is passed, next one is permissions check whether a user goes to /staff or /admin

Answer (score 0):

You need to check that token valid (has correct sign and not expired), then from validation process can get payload info. So basically you make middleware, which validates token and by payload either let request continue or return error response with corresponding code.

Comment: Token valid is passed, next one is permissions check whether a user goes to /staff or /admin ... etc

Comment: In request you ofc know to which path you accessing, and token payload is also availble, then just payload.premissions.includes(path), or maybe more complex match, in case path will have query params or just more deep.